# How to resolve a Javascript Scope issue. Is closure the answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, closures

I have a function

```
function getCustomAddress() {
    alert(results[i].formatted_address)
}
```

`alert(results[i].formatted_address)` is defined in another function. It clearly means that it is undefined in getCustomAddress, so how do I resolve this issue and alert the values. I have set up a fiddle as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/KEdrq/5/

Comment: If you post a jsfiddle example post a good one.

Comment: how do you want me to edit a fiffle, is it unclear? It couldnt get it to work by seperating scripts and markup guess because of callback nature.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass it as a function parameter

```
function getCustomAddress(result) {
    alert(result.formatted_address)
}
```

so when you call the function you need to supply one parameter:
getCustomAddress(results[i]);  for example

Answer (score 1):

You could create a private scope with a function and define all your global variables there:

```
(function(){
 var results = [];
 function getCustomerAdress(){
 //... call result etс
 }

 function set result(){
 //... set result etc
 }

 // some code for initialization, setting onload handlers etc
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the jsFiddle, the results are fetched as an ajax request.
You need to store the results in a variable with a global scope and then set a timeout to fetch the result. You can also execute your function before the end of geocoder request and pass it the results variable.

```
geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function (results, status) { 
  // execute your function here. getCustomAddress(result)
}
```

Check the changes I have made.
http://jsfiddle.net/KEdrq/7/

Summary of code changes.

```
 var _results;

 function initialize() {
.
.
.
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (e) {

         getAddress(e.latLng);
         setTimeout('getCustomAddress(0);', 500);
     })

     function getAddress(latLng) {
         if (!geocoder) {
             geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         }
         var geocoderRequest = {
             latLng: latLng
         }
         geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function (results, status) {
             _results = results;
.
.
.

 function getCustomAddress(i) {
     alert(_results[i].formatted_address)
 }
```

You might want to create a for loop to alert all the results instead of passing the result id in the getCustomAddress function.